# Enable and Disable Scroll Function in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, performance

```js
var pdfjsLib = window['pdfjs-dist/build/pdf'];
pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = 'https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.worker.js';
var PDFRenderingInProgress = false
var pdfDoc = null
var canvas = document.getElementById('the-canvas')
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var container = document.getElementById("div-container")

var url = 'https://d3bxy9euw4e147.cloudfront.net/oscms-prodcms/media/documents/Physics-WEB_Sab7RrQ.pdf';


var wheelTimeoutHandler = null;
var wheelTimeout = 250 //ms

function renderPage(scale) {
    pdfDoc.getPage(1).then(function(page) {
        var viewport = page.getViewport({scale: scale});
        canvas.height = viewport.height;
        canvas.width = viewport.width;
        var renderContext = {
            canvasContext: ctx,
            viewport: viewport
        };

        if (!PDFRenderingInProgress) {
            PDFRenderingInProgress = true
            var renderTask = page.render(renderContext);
            renderTask.promise.then(function() {
                PDFRenderingInProgress = false
            })
        }
  });
}

function zoomWithWheel(event) {
    panzoom.zoomWithWheel(event)
    clearTimeout(wheelTimeoutHandler);
    wheelTimeoutHandler = setTimeout(function() {
        canvas.style.transform = "scale("+1/panzoom.getScale()+")"
        if (pdfDoc)
            renderPage(panzoom.getScale());
    }, wheelTimeout)
}

pdfjsLib.getDocument(url).promise.then(function(pdfDoc_) {
    pdfDoc = pdfDoc_;
    renderPage(1);
});

var panzoom = Panzoom(container)
container.parentElement.addEventListener('wheel', zoomWithWheel)


function disable_scroll(){}

function enable_scroll(){}
```

```css
#the-canvas {
  direction: ltr;
  transform-origin: top left;
}
#div-container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@panzoom/panzoom@4.3.2/dist/panzoom.min.js"></script>

<button onclick="disable_scroll()">Disable Scroll Zoom</button>
<button onclick="enable_scroll()">Enable Scroll Zoom</button>


<div id="div-container">
  <canvas id="the-canvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

Above is a working code HTML with **Scroll Zoom Functionality** using the **Wheel of Your Mouse**,may I know how to enable and **enable or disable the scroll of the mouse** so that the PDF can be zoom-enabled and zoom-disabled?

I have tried to **remove the event listener to disable it**, but it does not work, unfortunately. I will really appreciate any help I can get :)

```
button.removeEventListener(“click”, myFunction);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do what you require you can use a single button to toggle the binding of the `wheel` event to the `zoomWithWheel` function, like this. Note the use of the `data` attribute to maintain state of the zoom toggle.

```
document.querySelector('#scroll-toggle').addEventListener('click', e => {
  const enabled = e.target.dataset.enabled == 'true'; // as dataset returns a string
  e.target.textContent = enabled ? 'Enable scroll zoom' : 'Disable scroll zoom';
  container.parentElement[enabled ? 'removeEventListener' : 'addEventListener']('wheel', zoomWithWheel)
  e.target.dataset.enabled = !enabled;
});
```

```js
const pdfjsLib = window['pdfjs-dist/build/pdf'];
pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = 'https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.worker.js';
let PDFRenderingInProgress = false
let pdfDoc = null
let canvas = document.getElementById('the-canvas')
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
let container = document.getElementById("div-container")

let url = 'https://d3bxy9euw4e147.cloudfront.net/oscms-prodcms/media/documents/Physics-WEB_Sab7RrQ.pdf';
let wheelTimeoutHandler = null;
let wheelTimeout = 250 //ms

function renderPage(scale) {
  pdfDoc.getPage(1).then(function(page) {
    var viewport = page.getViewport({
      scale: scale
    });
    canvas.height = viewport.height;
    canvas.width = viewport.width;
    var renderContext = {
      canvasContext: ctx,
      viewport: viewport
    };

    if (!PDFRenderingInProgress) {
      PDFRenderingInProgress = true
      var renderTask = page.render(renderContext);
      renderTask.promise.then(function() {
        PDFRenderingInProgress = false
      })
    }
  });
}

function zoomWithWheel(event) {
  panzoom.zoomWithWheel(event)
  clearTimeout(wheelTimeoutHandler);
  wheelTimeoutHandler = setTimeout(function() {
    canvas.style.transform = "scale(" + 1 / panzoom.getScale() + ")"
    if (pdfDoc)
      renderPage(panzoom.getScale());
  }, wheelTimeout)
}

pdfjsLib.getDocument(url).promise.then(function(pdfDoc_) {
  pdfDoc = pdfDoc_;
  renderPage(1);
});

const panzoom = Panzoom(container);

document.querySelector('#scroll-toggle').addEventListener('click', e => {
  const enabled = e.target.dataset.enabled == 'true'; // as dataset returns a string
  e.target.textContent = enabled ? 'Enable scroll zoom' : 'Disable scroll zoom';
  container.parentElement[enabled ? 'removeEventListener' : 'addEventListener']('wheel', zoomWithWheel)
  e.target.dataset.enabled = !enabled;
});
```

```css
#the-canvas {
  direction: ltr;
  transform-origin: top left;
}

#div-container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@panzoom/panzoom@4.3.2/dist/panzoom.min.js"></script>

<button id="scroll-toggle" data-enabled="false">Enable Scroll Zoom</button>


<div id="div-container">
  <canvas id="the-canvas"></canvas>
</div>
```